# What is a best way to implement web service sending data to browser

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am working on a web development project for following use case :-

Web front end ---->  Consumer service ---->  Producer Process

Producer process would continuously send data to consumer service. And when the request comes from web front end, consumer service would continuously send data received from producer after that point to front end.

My initial thoughts on this :-

1) Implement consumer service as `servlet`. After getting `doGet()` request from web front end, a separate thread will initialize the queue which will start storing the data to send to producer process.

2) Implement some kind of observer pattern where producer will be the Subject and web front end will be the observer.

Can anyone please shed some light on this.

Comment: take a look [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets-840092-dup) to ensure the continuous connection between front and back end.

Comment: Thanks that's a very helpful answer.